# Add attribute without name and value?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xelement, xattribute

Whether XML element attribute name can be empty:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test>
  <tables>
    <gg qqq="">
      <ss ""=""/>
      <mm ""=""/>
    </gg>
  </tables>
</test>
```

I am getting an exception I cant to load this. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, this will produce invalid XML. Attribute must have both name and value. How do you image opposite?

Comment: Sir, this is more useful as comment not an answer.

Comment: @Mayur: Why? OP asks is it possible. I answer that it is not. How to answer it more proper way?)

Comment: I see two options: answer as I did or downvote meaning this is a silly question. I choose first. I think there are not silly questions, there are people being lazy to google, and silly answers.

Answer (score 0):

No this can not be done.

XML has `empty element` concept[If you are trying to implement that].

In that whole element is kept empty and said to be null as follow>>

```
<abc></abc>
<DefaultTaxPrice></DefaultTaxPrice>
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no. If you want to add value but not know what is the name of the value in XML, insert in into the body instead.

```
<ss>value</ss>
```

This way, your ss will be treated as a value